# Total All Attributes for Model Type

Tags: ember.js

Using Ember Light Table, I generated a table with yearly batting statistics for a play. At the bottom of the table I'd like to have totals for every column. What's the best way to go about summing every attribute to get career totals?

I can't figure out whether I should manually create computed sums for each attribute (doing so would suck) or if there's a simpler way. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_sum

> A computed property that returns the sum of the values in the dependent array.

like:

```
totalCount: Ember.computed.sum('data.count'),
totalValue: Ember.computed.sum('data.value'),
```

Comment: But don't I have to do that for each attribute? Is there a way to output totals from all attributes in a template?

Comment: you don't want write multiple strings? You can try undefinedProperty but better create normal props